# addition of more than one dict in python

Tags: python, dictionary

i have 6 dict like this

```
dict1
dict2
dict3
dict4
dict5
dict6
```

now I want all of this in one dict. so I used this

```
dict1.update({'dict2':dict2}) 
dict3.update({'dict1':dict1})
dict4.update({'dict4':dict3})
dict5.update({'dict5':dict4})                           
dict6.update({'dict6':dict5})
```

at last ***dict6*** contains all value but it's not formatted correctly and it's not ***the pythonic*** way to do it

*I want to improve this any suggestions*

right now I'm getting like this but I don't want like this

```
{"main_responses": {"dict1": {"dict2": {"dict3": {"dict4": {"dict5": {}}}}}}}
```

***i want***

```
{"main_responses":{ "dict1": {dict1_values}, "dict2": {dict2_values}..... and so on
```

Comment: Pls provide your input and required output.

Comment: What do you mean "formatted correctly"; there is no standard way to format dictionaries.

Comment: I've added the description @KaushikNP

Comment: you can see the formation I'm talking about @BurhanKhalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving a very similar example of my own based on your requirements:

```
>>> d1 = {'a':1}
>>> d2 = {'b':2}
>>> d3 = {'c':3}
>>> d4 = {'d':4}

#magic happens here
>>> d = {'d1':d1 , 'd2':d2, 'd3':d3, 'd4':d4}
>>> d
=> {'d1': {'a': 1}, 'd2': {'b': 2}, 'd3': {'c': 3}, 'd4': {'d': 4}}
```

**Since** you do not have all the dictionaries that you want added in one place, this is about as easy as it gets.

In case you want to add another `key` to your *collection of all dictionaries* (`d` here), do:

```
>>> out = {'api_responses': d}

#or in one step if you do not want to use `d`
>>> out = {'api_responses': {'d1':d1 , 'd2':d2, 'd3':d3, 'd4':d4}}

>>> out
=> {'api_responses': {'d1': {'a': 1}, 'd2': {'b': 2}, 'd3': {'c': 3}, 'd4': {'d': 4}}}
```

Comment: just one question if I got any dict blank than what would I probably get? @KaushikNP can you suggest anything for tackle that situation

Comment: @manan_kalariya : something like `{'api_responses': {'d1': {}, 'd2': {}, 'd3': {'c': 3}, 'd4': {'d': 4}}}` supposing your `d1` and `d2` are empty.

Comment: yes but as I'm creating dict dynamically than there are many situation in which `'d1': {}` even {}(blanck dict) is not creating than what can i do ?

Comment: @manan_kalariya : If its not created at the time of declaring the final dictionary, keep a dummy placeholder of `None` for that element and then update it when your required `dictionary` is created.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from itertools import chain
d = chain.from_iterable(d.items() for d in (ada_dict, 
                                        wordpress_version_dict,
                                        drupal_version_dict,
                                        ssl_dict,
                                        link_dict,
                                        tag_dict)) 

api_response = {'api_response':d}
```

---

Or this, using `reduce`:

```
d = reduce(lambda x,y: dict(x, **y), (ada_dict, 
                                  wordpress_version_dict,
                                  drupal_version_dict,
                                  ssl_dict,
                                  link_dict,
                                  tag_dict))

api_response = {'api_response':d}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want add all dict in a single one "newDict", Be carrefull if several keys exist in multiple Dict :

```
ada_dict={'k1':'v1'}
wordpress_version_dict={'k2':'v2'}
drupal_version_dict={'k3':'v3'}
ssl_dict={'k4':'v4'}
link_dict={'k5':'v5'}
tag_dict={'k5':'v5'}

newDict={}
newDict.update( (k,v) for k,v in ada_dict.iteritems() if v is not None)
newDict.update( (k,v) for k,v in wordpress_version_dict.iteritems() if v is not None)
newDict.update( (k,v) for k,v in drupal_version_dict.iteritems() if v is not None)
newDict.update( (k,v) for k,v in ssl_dict.iteritems() if v is not None)
newDict.update( (k,v) for k,v in link_dict.iteritems() if v is not None)
newDict.update( (k,v) for k,v in tag_dict.iteritems() if v is not None)

print {'api_response':newDict}
```

https://repl.it/ND3p/1

Answer (score 0):

please add more comment to your post, but as I see you need something like , is not it ?

```
>>> foo=lambda dest, src, tag: [dest.update({tag:i}) for i in src]
>>> x={1:1}
>>> y={2:2}
>>> foo(x, y, "tag")
[None]
>>> x
{1: 1, 'tag': 2}
>>> y
{2: 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help in getting the output you want?

```
   new_dict=dict(ada_dict.items()+wordpress_version_dict.items() +drupal_version_dict.items()+ssl_dict.items()+link_dict.items()+tag_dict.items())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 a =[ada_dict,
wordpress_version_dict,
drupal_version_dict,
ssl_dict,
link_dict,
tag_dict]

 c= {}

for i in a:
    c.update({i:i})

print c
{'ada_dict': 'ada_dict',
 'drupal_version_dict': 'drupal_version_dict',
 'link_dict': 'link_dict',
 'ssl_dict': 'ssl_dict',
 'tag_dict': 'tag_dict',
 'wordpress_version_dic': 'wordpress_version_dic'}
d={}
d.update({"api_responses":c})
print d

{'api_responses': {'ada_dict': 'ada_dict',
  'drupal_version_dict': 'drupal_version_dict',
  'link_dict': 'link_dict',
  'ssl_dict': 'ssl_dict',
  'tag_dict': 'tag_dict',
  'wordpress_version_dic': 'wordpress_version_dic'}}
```